# Spring-Hibernate-JPA-Spring-Data-Maven-JSF Application Tomcat Startup Error

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, jpa

I'm starting a Spring-Hibernate-JPA-Spring-Data-Maven-JSF Application in Eclipse-Mars, using Tomcat 8. I'm getting startup errors when attempting to start the server, and I've tried to fix this for over a week, and I thought its time to ask for help!

Here is some of the Tomcat error printout from the console:

```
  ...
    08:47:10.900 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.b.f.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]
  ...
    08:47:10.981 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR o.s.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
    org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 23 in XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 23; columnNumber: 67; cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'.
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:399) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:336) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    ...
SEVERE: One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
    May 10, 2016 8:47:15 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
    SEVERE: Context [/SilentHomeCemetery_Maven] startup failed due to previous errors
    May 10, 2016 8:47:15 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
    INFO: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
    08:47:15.465 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.w.c.s.XmlWebApplicationContext - Closing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Tue May 10 08:47:10 EDT 2016]; root of context hierarchy
    08:47:15.472 [localhost-startStop-1] WARN  o.s.w.c.s.XmlWebApplicationContext - Exception thrown from LifecycleProcessor on context close
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: LifecycleProcessor not initialized - call 'refresh' before invoking lifecycle methods via the context: Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Tue May 10 08:47:10 EDT 2016]; root of context hierarchy
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getLifecycleProcessor(AbstractApplicationContext.java:414) [spring-context-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
```

Here is my web.xml File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
      <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
      </listener>
      <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener
        </listener-class>
      </listener>  
      <context-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>
                /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml           
            </param-value>
      </context-param>
      <context-param>  
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
      </context-param>
      <context-param>
            <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_LIBRARIES</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/springsecurity.taglib.xml</param-value>
      </context-param> 
      <!-- 
      <filter>
            <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
            <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
        </filter>
        <filter-mapping>
            <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
      </filter-mapping>
       -->
       <filter>
            <filter-name>loginFilter</filter-name>
            <filter-class>com.kletus.silentHomeCemetery.filters.LoginFilter</filter-class>
       </filter>
       <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>loginFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/Admin/*</url-pattern>
       </filter-mapping>
       <filter>
            <filter-name>preventLoginFilter</filter-name>
            <filter-class>com.kletus.silentHomeCemetery.filters.PreventLoginFilter</filter-class>
       </filter>
       <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>preventLoginFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/index.xhtml</url-pattern> 
       </filter-mapping>   
      <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
      </servlet>

      <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>  
      <!-- Map these files with JSF -->   
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>      
      </servlet-mapping>  

      <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>/faces/index.xhtml</welcome-file>    
    </welcome-file-list>

     <context-param>
            <description>State saving method: 'client' or 'server' (=default). See JSF Specification 2.5.2</description>
            <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
            <param-value>client</param-value>
        </context-param>

      <session-config>
        <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
      </session-config>
    </web-app>
```

Here is my applicationContext.xml File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans
       xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans:beans"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"       
       xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
       xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
               http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd       
               http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd">

    <!--    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa-1.2.xsd"> -->

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven/>

     <!-- Package needed to be scanned for annotation -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="spring"/>

    <!-- Use annotation for configuration-->
    <context:annotation-config/>
    <context:spring-configured/>

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving 
        up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" /> 

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.db2.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:db2://localhost:50000/SLNTRURO" />
        <property name="username" value="<name>" />
        <property name="password" value="<password>" />
    </bean>    

    <!-- Hibernate 4 SessionFactory Bean definition -->
    <bean id="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>com.kletus.silentHomeCemetery.model.jpa.GraveInfo</value>
                <value>com.kletus.silentHomeCemetery.model.jpa.Control</value>
                <value>com.kletus.silentHomeCemetery.model.jpa.Encrypted_lot_info</value>
                <value>com.kletus.silentHomeCemetery.model.jpa.EncryptedGraveInfo</value>
                <value>com.kletus.silentHomeCemetery.model.jpa.EncryptionKey</value>
                <value>com.kletus.silentHomeCemetery.model.jpa.LotInfo</value>                
                <value>com.kletus.silentHomeCemetery.model.jpa.Security</value> 
                <value>com.kletus.silentHomeCemetery.model.jpa.SilentHomeUser</value>    
                <value>com.kletus.silentHomeCemetery.model.jpa.UserRole</value> 
                <value>com.kletus.silentHomeCemetery.model.jpa.Role</value>           

            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.DB2Dialect
                </prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>    

    <bean id="UserDAO" class="com.kletus.silentHomeCemetery.DAO.UserDAO">
        <property name="sessionFactory"
            ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.kletus.silentHomeCemetery" />

    <bean id="persistenceUnitManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager">
    <!-- <property name="defaultPersistenceUnitName" value="nutrition-pu"/> -->
    <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath:META-INF/persistence.xml"/>
    <property name="defaultDataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

    <!-- JPA -->
    <bean id="entityManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="persistenceUnitManager" ref="persistenceUnitManager" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaVendorAdapter" />
    </bean>

    <!-- jpaVendorAdapter (works in conjunction with the persistence.xml) -->
    <bean id="jpaVendorAdapter"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
        <property name="database" value="${jpa.database}" />
        <property name="showSql" value="${jpa.showSql}" />
        <property name="databasePlatform" value="${jpa.dialect}" />
        <property name="generateDdl" value="${jpa.generateDdl}" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.kletus.silentHomeCemetery.model.jpa" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManager" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="persistenceAnnotation" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />   

</beans>
```

Here is my eclipselink-orm.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <entity-mappings version="2.5" xmlns="http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/persistence/orm" 
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/persistence/orm http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/eclipselink_orm_2_5.xsd">
        <named-query name="Control.findAll">
            <query>select c from Control c</query>
        </named-query>
        <named-query name="Encrypted_lot_info.findAll">
            <query>select e from Encrypted_lot_info e</query>
        </named-query>
        <named-query name="EncryptedGraveInfo.findAll">
            <query>select e from EncryptedGraveInfo e</query>
        </named-query>
        <named-query name="EncryptionKey.findAll">
            <query>select e from EncryptionKey e</query>
        </named-query>
        <named-query name="LotInfo.findAll">
            <query>select l from LotInfo l</query>
        </named-query>        
        <named-query name="Security.findAll">
            <query>select s from Security s</query>
        </named-query>

        <named-query name="SilentHomeUser.findAll">
            <query>select u from SilentHomeUser u</query>
        </named-query>

        <named-query name="UserRole.findAll">
            <query>select z from UserRole z</query>
        </named-query>

        <named-query name="Role.findAll">
            <query>select r from Role r</query>
        </named-query>

        <entity class="com.kletus.silentHomeCemetery.model.jpa.Control" access="VIRTUAL">
            <table name="CONTROLS"/>
            <attributes>
                <id name="controlKey" attribute-type="int">
                    <column name="CONTROL_KEY"/>
                    <generated-value strategy="AUTO"/>
                </id>
                <basic name="dateLastBackup" attribute-type="java.util.Date">
                    <column name="DATE_LAST_BACKUP"/>
                    <temporal>DATE</temporal>
                </basic>
                <basic name="dateLastCompact" attribute-type="java.util.Date">
                    <column name="DATE_LAST_COMPACT"/>
                    <temporal>DATE</temporal>
                </basic>
            </attributes>
        </entity>
        <entity class="com.kletus.silentHomeCemetery.model.jpa.Encrypted_lot_info" access="VIRTUAL">
            <table name='"ENCRYPTED LOT INFO"'/>
            <attributes>
                <id name="eLotId" attribute-type="int">
                    <column name="E_LOT_ID"/>
                    <generated-value strategy="AUTO"/>
                </id>
                <basic name="eLot" attribute-type="String">
                    <column name="E_LOT"/>
                </basic>
                <basic name="eLotAddDate" attribute-type="String">
                    <column name="E_LOT_ADD_DATE"/>
                </basic>
                <basic name="eLotChgDate" attribute-type="String">
                    <column name="E_LOT_CHG_DATE"/>
                </basic>
                <basic name="eLotName" attribute-type="String">
                    <column name="E_LOT_NAME"/>
                </basic>
                <basic name="eLotNextOfKin" attribute-type="String">
                    <column name="E_LOT_NEXT_OF_KIN"/>
                </basic>
                <basic name="eLotNotes" attribute-type="String">
                    <column name="E_LOT_NOTES"/>
                </basic>
                <basic name="eLotOrigLotNbr" attribute-type="String">
                    <column name="E_LOT_ORIG_LOT_NBR"/>
                </basic>
                <basic name="eLotUniqId" attribute-type="String">
                    <column name="E_LOT_UNIQ_ID"/>
                </basic>
                <basic name="eUserName" attribute-type="String">
                    <column name="E_USER_NAME"/>
                </basic>
                <basic name="key" attribute-type="String">
                    <column name='"KEY"'/>
                </basic>
            </attributes>
        </entity>
        <entity class="com.kletus.silentHomeCemetery.model.jpa.EncryptedGraveInfo" access="VIRTUAL">
            <table name="ENCRYPTED_GRAVE_INFO"/>
            <attributes>
                <id name="eGraveId" attribute-type="int">
                    <column name="E_GRAVE_ID"/>
                    <generated-value strategy="AUTO"/>
                </id>
                <basic name="dateLastChanged" attribute-type="java.sql.Timestamp">
                    <column name="DATE_LAST_CHANGED"/>
                </basic>
                <basic name="eDeathDate" attribute-type="String">
                    <column name="E_DEATH_DATE"/>
                </basic>
                <basic name="eGraveAddDate" attribute-type="String">
                    <column name="E_GRAVE_ADD_DATE"/>
                </basic>
                <basic name="eGraveChgDate" attribute-type="String">
                    <column name="E_GRAVE_CHG_DATE"/>
                </basic>
                <basic name="eGraveDate" attribute-type="String">
                    <column name="E_GRAVE_DATE"/>
                </basic>
                <basic name="eGraveFuneralDirector" attribute-type="String">
                    <column name="E_GRAVE_FUNERAL_DIRECTOR"/>
                </basic>
                <basic name="eGraveLot" attribute-type="String">
                    <column name="E_GRAVE_LOT"/>
                </basic>
                <basic name="eGraveLotUniqId" attribute-type="String">
                    <column name="E_GRAVE_LOT_UNIQ_ID"/>
                </basic>
                <basic name="eGraveName" attribute-type="String">
                    <column name="E_GRAVE_NAME"/>
                </basic>
                <basic name="eGraveNbr" attribute-type="String">
                    <column name="E_GRAVE_NBR"/>
                </basic>
                <basic name="eGraveNotes" attribute-type="String">
                    <column name="E_GRAVE_NOTES"/>
                </basic>
                <basic name="eUserName" attribute-type="String">
                    <column name="E_USER_NAME"/>
                </basic>
                <basic name="encryptedGraveId" attribute-type="String">
                    <column name="ENCRYPTED_GRAVE_ID"/>
                </basic>
                <basic name="key" attribute-type="String">
                    <column name='"KEY"'/>
                </basic>
            </attributes>
        </entity>
        <entity class="com.kletus.silentHomeCemetery.model.jpa.EncryptionKey" access="VIRTUAL">
            <table name="ENCRYPTION_KEYS"/>
            <attributes>
                <id name="keyTracker" attribute-type="long">
                    <column name="KEY_TRACKER"/>
                    <generated-value strategy="AUTO"/>
                </id>
                <basic name="key" attribute-type="String">
                    <column name='"KEY"'/>
                </basic>
            </attributes>
        </entity>
        <entity class="com.kletus.silentHomeCemetery.model.jpa.LotInfo" access="VIRTUAL">
            <table name="LOT_INFO"/>
            <attributes>
                <id name="lotUniqId" attribute-type="int">
                    <column name="LOT_UNIQ_ID"/>
                    <generated-value strategy="AUTO"/>
                </id>
                <basic name="encryption_key" attribute-type="byte[]">
                    <column name='"ENCRYPTION KEY"'/>
                </basic>
                <basic name="lot" attribute-type="int">
                </basic>
                <basic name="lotAddDate" attribute-type="java.util.Date">
                    <column name="LOT_ADD_DATE"/>
                    <temporal>DATE</temporal>
                </basic>
                <basic name="lotChgDate" attribute-type="java.sql.Timestamp">
                    <column name="LOT_CHG_DATE"/>
                </basic>
                <basic name="lotName" attribute-type="String">
                    <column name="LOT_NAME"/>
                </basic>
                <basic name="lotNextOfKin" attribute-type="String">
                    <column name="LOT_NEXT_OF_KIN"/>
                </basic>
                <basic name="lotNotes" attribute-type="String">
                    <column name="LOT_NOTES"/>
                </basic>
                <basic name="lotOrigLotNbr" attribute-type="String">
                    <column name="LOT_ORIG_LOT_NBR"/>
                </basic>
                <basic name="userName" attribute-type="String">
                    <column name="USER_NAME"/>
                </basic>
            </attributes>
        </entity>
        <entity class="com.kletus.silentHomeCemetery.model.jpa.GraveInfo" access="VIRTUAL">
            <table name="GRAVE_INFO"/>
            <attributes>
                <id name="GraveId" attribute-type="int">
                    <column name="GRAVE_ID"/>
                    <generated-value strategy="AUTO"/>
                </id>
                <basic name="graveChgDate" attribute-type="java.sql.Timestamp">
                    <column name="GRAVE_CHG_DATE"/>
                </basic>
                <basic name="deathDate" attribute-type="java.sql.Timestamp">
                    <column name="DEATH_DATE"/>
                </basic>
                <basic name="graveAddDate" attribute-type="java.sql.Timestamp">
                    <column name="GRAVE_ADD_DATE"/>
                </basic>            
                <basic name="graveDate" attribute-type="String">
                    <column name="GRAVE_DATE"/>
                </basic>
                <basic name="graveFuneralDirector" attribute-type="String">
                    <column name="GRAVE_FUNERAL_DIRECTOR"/>
                </basic>
                <basic name="graveLot" attribute-type="String">
                    <column name="GRAVE_LOT"/>
                </basic>
                <basic name="graveLotUniqId" attribute-type="String">
                    <column name="GRAVE_LOT_UNIQ_ID"/>
                </basic>
                <basic name="graveName" attribute-type="String">
                    <column name="GRAVE_NAME"/>
                </basic>
                <basic name="graveNbr" attribute-type="String">
                    <column name="GRAVE_NBR"/>
                </basic>
                <basic name="graveNotes" attribute-type="String">
                    <column name="GRAVE_NOTES"/>
                </basic>
                <basic name="userName" attribute-type="String">
                    <column name="USER_NAME"/>
                </basic>
                <basic name="encryptKey" attribute-type="Byte">
                    <column name='"ENCRYPT_KEY"'/>
                </basic>
            </attributes>
        </entity>

        <embeddable class='com.kletus.silentHomeCemetery.model.jpa.UserRolePK"' access="VIRTUAL">
            <attributes>
                <basic name="userId" attribute-type="int">
                    <column name="USER_ID"/>
                </basic>
                <basic name="roleId" attribute-type="int">
                    <column name="ROLE_ID"/>
                </basic>
            </attributes>
        </embeddable>

        <entity class='com.kletus.silentHomeCemetery.model.jpa.UserRole"' access="VIRTUAL">
            <table name="USER_ROLES"/>
            <attributes>
                <id name="userId" attribute-type="int">
                    <column name="USER_ID"/>                
                </id>           
                <basic name="roleId" attribute-type="int">
                    <column name="ROLE_ID"/>
                </basic>
            </attributes>
        </entity>

        <entity class='com.kletus.silentHomeCemetery.model.jpa.Role"' access="VIRTUAL">
            <table name="ROLES"/>
            <attributes>
                <id name="roleId" attribute-type="int">
                    <column name="ROLE_ID"/>                
                </id>           
                <basic name="role" attribute-type="String">
                    <column name="ROLE"/>
                </basic>
            </attributes>
        </entity>       

        <entity class='com.kletus.silentHomeCemetery.model.jpa.SilentHomeUser"' access="VIRTUAL">
            <table name="SILENT_HOME_USER"/>
            <attributes>
                <id name="userId" attribute-type="int">
                    <column name="USER_ID"/>                
                </id>           
                <basic name="activeInd" attribute-type="int">
                    <column name="ACTIVE_IND"/>
                </basic>
                <basic name="fName" attribute-type="String">
                    <column name="FNAME"/>
                </basic>
                <basic name="mName" attribute-type="String">
                    <column name="MNAME"/>
                </basic>
                <basic name="lName" attribute-type="String">
                    <column name="LNAME"/>
                </basic>
                <basic name="password" attribute-type="String">
                    <column name="PASSWORD"/>
                </basic>
            </attributes>
        </entity>   

    </entity-mappings>
```

Here is my spring-config.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans:beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd        
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.kletus.SilentHomeCemetery" />

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath:/persistence.xml" />
        <!-- <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="userPersistenceUnit" /> -->
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaVendorAdapter" />
        <property name="jpaDialect" ref="jpaDialect" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="jpaVendorAdapter" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
        <property name="database" value="DB2" />
        <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.DB2Dialect" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="jpaDialect" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect" />

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="jpaDialect" ref="jpaDialect" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver" />    
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:db2://localhost:50000/SLNTRURO:retrieveMessagesFromServerOnGetMessage=true;" />   

        <property name="username" value="<name>" />
        <property name="password" value="<password">"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Comment: Please post only necessary segments from your code. Its hard to figure out what's wrong from such a huge codebase

Comment: Sorry, first time asking a question.

Comment: The stack trace is very clear about this: The error is in your applicationContext.xml. I'm no spring expert, but have you tried replacing `xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans:beans"` by `xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"`

Comment: Yes, I tried that as well, it causes a compilation error "cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'annotation-driven'. One of '{"http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":description, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/
 beans":import, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":alias, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":bean, WC[##other:"http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"], "http://
 www.springframework.org/schema/beans":beans}' is expected."

Comment: @JohnM.Yount, no problem. Just edit your question and remove un-necessary parts

Answer (score 2):

You have an error in the schema declaration.

```
xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans:beans"
```

should be

```
xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
```

That's the default namespace for the `applicationContext.xml`. Logs are clearly showing that.

```
lineNumber: 23; columnNumber: 67; cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'.
```

Comment: Well, I tried that, putting in xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans", and it causes a compilation error "cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'annotation-driven'. One of '{"springframework.org/schema/beans":description, "springframework.org/schema beans":import, "springframework.org/schema/beans":alias, "springframework.org/schema/beans":bean, WC[##other:"springframework.org/schema/beans"], "http:// www.springframework.org/schema/beans":beans}' is expected."

Comment: `<annotation-driven>` is in `mvc` namespace, you'll need to include ` xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"`, If you're using STS, that'll make adding and removing schema declaration easier.

Comment: OK, I changed the xmlns="springframework.org/schema/beans:bean" to xmlns="springframework.org/schema/beans", and I added xmlns:mvc="springframework.org/schema/mvc". Still getting the same compile error "cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'annotation-driven'. One of '{"springframework.org/schema/beans":description, "springframework.org/schema beans":import, "springframework.org/schema/beans":alias, "springframework.org/schema/beans":bean, WC[##other:"springframework.org/schema/beans"], "http:// www.springframework.org/schema/beans":beans}' is expected."

Comment: Anybody out there have any ideas? I'm getting close to giving up and starting over. I can't fix this on my own.

Answer (score 0):

Well, after banging my head against the wall for weeks, I finally got the application to work. I'm still not sure why this applicationContext.xml file works, because it does not look like any other applicationContext.xml file I've ever seen, but it does, and I'm not going to question success, I'm just going to go with it. If I swap the "beans:beans" xml element, and replace it with a standard "beans" format, I get all kinds of compilation errors, and Tomcat 8 will not start. If anyone has any ideas why this works, and the standard "beans" element does not, I would be really interested to learn why.

Thanks so much to the Stack Overflow community for the help & encouragement, I really appreciate it!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans
   xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
xmlns:repository="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/repository"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-4.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/repository http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/repository/spring-repository-1.0.xsd">


<!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
<annotation-driven />

 <!-- Package needed to be scanned for annotation -->
<context:component-scan base-package="spring"/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.base.silentHomeCemetery" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.base.silentHomeCemetery"/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.base.silentHomeCemetery.model.jpa"/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.base.silentHomeCemetery.DAO"/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.base.silentHomeCemetery.model.repository"/>
<context:component-scan
base-package="com.base.silentHomeCemetery.model.repository.Impl"/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.base.silentHomeCemetery.service"/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.base.silentHomeCemetery.service.Impl"/>

<!-- Use annotation for configuration-->
<context:annotation-config/>
<context:spring-configured/>

<!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving 
    up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />      

<beans:bean id="userDAO" class="com.base.silentHomeCemetery.DAO.UserDAO">  
    <beans:property name="userDAO" ref="userDAO"/>
    <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory" />
</beans:bean>   

<beans:bean id="dataSource"
            class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource" >       
    <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver"/>
    <beans:property name="url"
        value="jdbc:db2://localhost:50000/SLNTRURO" />
    <beans:property name="username" value="name" />
    <beans:property name="password" value="password" />
</beans:bean>

<!-- Hibernate 4 SessionFactory Bean definition -->
<beans:bean id="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <beans:property name="annotatedClasses">
        <beans:list>
            <beans:value>com.base.silentHomeCemetery.model.jpa.GraveInfo</beans:value>
            <beans:value>com.base.silentHomeCemetery.model.jpa.Control</beans:value>
            <beans:value>com.base.silentHomeCemetery.model.jpa.Encrypted_lot_info</beans:value>
            <beans:value>com.base.silentHomeCemetery.model.jpa.EncryptedGraveInfo</beans:value>
            <beans:value>com.base.silentHomeCemetery.model.jpa.EncryptionKey</beans:value>
            <beans:value>com.base.silentHomeCemetery.model.jpa.LotInfo</beans:value>                
            <beans:value>com.base.silentHomeCemetery.model.jpa.Security</beans:value> 
            <beans:value>com.base.silentHomeCemetery.model.jpa.SilentHomeUser</beans:value>    
            <beans:value>com.base.silentHomeCemetery.model.jpa.UserRole</beans:value> 
            <beans:value>com.base.silentHomeCemetery.model.jpa.Role</beans:value>           

        </beans:list>
    </beans:property>
    <beans:property name="hibernateProperties">
        <beans:props>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.DB2Dialect
            </beans:prop>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</beans:prop>
        </beans:props>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="entityManagerFactory" p:dataSource-ref="dataSource"
 class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <beans:property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath:/META-INF/eclipselink-
<orm.xml" />
    <beans:property name="packagesToScan" value="com.base.silentHomeCemetery" />
    <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />

    <beans:property name="jpaProperties">
        <beans:props>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</beans:prop>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</beans:prop>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.DB2Dialect</beans:prop>
        </beans:props>
    </beans:property>

    <beans:property name="persistenceProvider">
        <beans:bean class="org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider"/>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>


<beans:bean id="log4jInitialization"
 class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">  
    <beans:property name="targetClass" value="org.springframework.util.Log4jConfigurer"/>
    <beans:property name="targetMethod" value="initLogging"/>
    <beans:property name="arguments">
        <beans:list>
            <beans:value>log4j.properties</beans:value>
            <beans:value>WEB-INF/classes/log4j.xml</beans:value>classpath:/config/log4j-    silentHomeCemetery.xml NO classpath:/log4j.xml NO
        </beans:list>
    </beans:property>   
</beans:bean>   

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<beans:bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory" />
</beans:bean>
```